# React-S3 error: ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up file upload to S3 with React. I use React-S3

This is my code

```
const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    S3FileUpload
    .uploadFile(selectedFile, awsConfig)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  };
```

I have the error **ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined** in my console. Can you help me please?

Comment: Is the error coming from above code? Are you using Buffer in selectedFile part or something?

Answer (score 2):

`npm i buffer`

Then import it at the top of your file like so:

`window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;`

source: https://github.com/Fausto95/aws-s3/issues/88#issuecomment-1000511145